# Replace content of this <td> with id of next <td> onLoad

Tags: jquery, html

Given the following table, the first `<td>`'s content should be replaced with the next `td.input`'s `id` (the second value after splitting the id).

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>one</span></td>
      <td id="test"><span><input id="rjaxWMQBmoH-HllvX50cXC0-val" name="entryfield" title="element" value="[ one ]"     /></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So that the the first `<td>` becomes `<td><span>HllvX50cXC0</span></td>` on load.
I can see the method `$(this).next()` listing it under `lastChildren` but I wonder if that's the right method?

Comment: Questions on SO are better received if you've shown an attempt, at least....

Comment: what is generating the id? surely it would be better to do this server side?

Comment: yes I agree but it's a HTML form generated on the server where you can download the file later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few aspects of your question, and your markup, that make this a bit less-than-clear, but the below commented jQuery does what you've asked.

```js
// no-conflict-safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // loop through all inputs contained inside of a td
  $('td input').each(function() {
    // load the id of the input
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // if the id exists, and has a - in it, then....
    if (id && id.indexOf('-') > 0) {
      // split the id into parts (regex would also work here)
      id = id.split('-');
      // get the second part of the id
      id = id[1];
      // put the id into the previous cell's contents
      $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('span').text(id);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>one</span></td>
      <td id="test"><span><input id="rjaxWMQBmoH-HllvX50cXC0-val" name="entryfield" title="element" value="[ one ]"     /></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There's a handful of ways to slice this, this is just one one.

The key with jQuery is to use good selectors,  plus a clear understanding of the preferred DOM navigation functions.  I strongly recommend [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) (as opposed to [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/), which have gotchas that are avoided by using closest / find).

Comment: @mplungjan - indeed, answer was being updated while you added your on-point comment!

Comment: Alternative selector saves looking for one with an ID: `$('td input[name=entryfield][id]').each(function() {`

Comment: @mplungjan - yep! Totally agree.  Lots of ways to do this, and certainly room for optimizations!